# MS Teams outgoing webhook with python bot (bot framework) authentication with HMAC

Tags: python, botframework, webhooks, microsoft-teams, hmac

I'm trying to register a [MS Teams outgoing webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook) to handle user requests. The bot has been built using [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python). The bot is working properly when tested with the Bot Framework Emulator, but when I send messages from Teams, I get a `401-unauthorized`.

When I registered my outgoing webhook I got the HMAC key, but I don't know where to use it when setting up the bot using the Bot Framework. The options I see are to pass AppId and AppPassword but I don't have those because I can't register an app; I only have permissions to register an outgoing webhook.

So the question is: Can I instantiate a bot developed with the Bot Framework and set it up to respond user messages sent via Teams outgoing webhook? Where should I put the HMAC key?

Comment: Where are you seeing the 401? Also, have you configured you bot's AppId and AppPassword properly? If not, the emulator will work fine, but Teams will not for anything (either webhook or regular "bot" messaging) - exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have added Bot id and password in your application's config page? Also, please take a look at How to [configure outgoing webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook) and here is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook#code-samples) for the same.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I'm seeing the 401 in ngrok and in Teams I'm receiving a "There was a problem with your request". And no, I haven't configured an AppId and AppPassword because I don't have access to those options (due to admin restraints); so I'm stuck with outgoing webhooks.

Comment: Also I've managed to receive some responses from a regular webhook configuration, but without authentication (I'd have to implement the HMAC handshake) so the outgoing webhook is working fine. What I'd like is to use the Bot Framework but without the AppId and AppPassword if that's possible (only with the HMAC)

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT I've looked into it deeply. The thing is, those examples are not with python and are not with the Bot Framework. I've managed to do something similar to those examples with python but that 's building the endpoint, and response and managing security manually and I'd like to leverage the Bot Framework capabilities if that's possible.

Comment: You'll need to get the appid and app password - they're essential for securing certain parts of the workings of a bot. This blog post might be useful to understand that: https://hilton.giesenow.com/how-bot-calls-actually-work

Comment: @antorqs - Are you still working on this? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney I stopped going down this path. I ended up implementing my own bot handling the HMAC verification (a simple endpoint with the HMAC calculation) and I ditched all Bot Framework part. A shame because it was comfortable working with, but I couldn't make it work.